# array slice taking part of value instead of values

Tags: php, arrays

we are trying to get 2 widgets from our array into 1 slide but the array_slice is taking 2 letters from the link not 2 links from the array

```
public function get_right_widget($id){
$statement=$this->database->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM page_widget 
LEFT JOIN widget ON page_widget.widget_id = widget.widget_id WHERE 
page_id=:id");
$statement->bindParam(':id', $id);

$statement->execute();

return $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($widget->get_right_widget($screen_id) as $widgets) {

echo implode(array_slice($widgets,0,2));
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: ^ was about to ask this, can you explain more?

Comment: i had posted it wrong i edited the question

Comment: `LIMIT 2` in the query.

Comment: @u_mulder unfortunantly this won't work we need the next 2 widgets for the next slide

Comment: _“but the array_slice is taking 2 letters from the link not 2 links from the array”_ - you are not applying it to your array, you are applying it to a single item from that array, $widgets. You need to do this slicing _first_, and _then_ loop over the resulting array.

Comment: Please include an example of the input array, expected result from that example data and what result you're currently getting.